# Azure Table Storage: Retrieve all data by the same, specific partition key

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to retrieve a list of orderitems with the same orderID (orderID as the partition keys) from the table storage. For example: U001, and under one orderID there will be multiple productsID acting as rowkeys linked under the aforementioned U001 orderID.

The problem is so far with my knowledge you only can retrieve a table storage's by specifically mentioning BOTH the partition key and rowkey. Is there anyway to get all the data in the table storage by the only specifying the partition key?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is so far with my knowledge you only can retrieve a table
> storage's by specifically mentioning BOTH the partition key and
> rowkey.

Not true. Considering a partition key/row key combination uniquely identifies an entity, if you want to fetch a single entity then you would specify both partition key and row key to get that entity.

> Is there anyway to get all the data in the table storage by the only
> specifying the partition key?

Yes. You would need to query entities in your table for that. You query (filter criteria) would be `PartitionKey eq 'your-partition-key'`. That way you will be able to fetch entities matching your partition key.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities.